# Who is doing the wanting in this sentence?

Tags: reading-comprehension

From [this article](http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10010903891000/k10010903891000.html) talking about the evacuees from Fukushima experiencing bad treatment from people in the places to which they have evacuated:

> 早稲田大学の教授は「避難した人たちは家やふるさとをなくして、**今もつらい生活をしていることを忘れないでほしいです**」と話しています。
>   A professor of X university said "The evacuees have lost their houses and home town. Even now they don't want to forget about painful living."

Who is doing the wanting (ほしい) in the bold sentence? My English translation attempt sounds weird. It makes it sounds like the evacuees are complaining about thier bad treatment because they want to feel oppressed. Why would they not want to forget about hardship?

I would have expected something more like:

> 今もつらい生活をしていることを忘れることができないです
>   Even now they are unable to forget about hard living

What's wrong with my understanding here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The professor doesn't want you to forget about that.

It would start from "Please don't forget that..." or "I hope you don't forget that...".